# Two Divs, Same CSS, Same Line

Tags: css, html

I would like to use the same CSS for two boxes and keep'em in the same line with a little space between . I am not very familiar with css.
This is my code :

```
div.box {
    width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0œpx;
    margin :20px 0px 20px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 19px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.82);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 19px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.82);
    box-shadow: 0px 19px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.82);
}
```

[image]
Changing width to 48 or 47% can be a solution, but I don't think it's the good way .

Comment: Change margin & padding values to `%`

Comment: Why not? you cant use margin and 50%.. because 2 times 50 is 100% and you still have to add the size of the margin.. so 48% is a good solution, if you dont make it less than 50% the boxes wil get under eachother..

Comment: Yes, changing margin to % and using 48% helped me . I was thinking that I was able to do it using 50%. Thank you both .

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
div.box {
    width: 49%;
    display: block;
    float:left;

    min-height:100px;

    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0œpx;

    margin :20px 0px 20px 0px;
    margin-left:2%;

    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 19px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.82);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 19px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.82);
    box-shadow: 0px 19px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.82);
}
div.box:first-child{
   margin-left:0;
}
```

[image]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Gm3Ub/)